# Use Google Analytics to record newsletter clicks to an external website

Tags: google-analytics

Note: by external website I mean a website that we do not have access to the code. For example www.facebook.com

I want to record how many social share clicks we have from our customer newsletters. For example, when a customer receives a newsletter they can click "Share this on Facebook" which shares the hosted version of the newsletter.

If I wanted to record these newsletter clicks to our website I understand we'd use Google URL Builder (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) to create a UTM URL but because we're linking to an external site, how do we record this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot insert Analytics Code at the target site then the easiest (and probably only) way would be to send them to a page on your own domain that records the click and then redirects to the intended URL.   (This is how e-mail tracking in most professional newsletter software packages works in any case.)

Answer (score 0):

You could embed a tracking pixel in your content. This is possible on Facebook (AFAIK) by using the power editor.

There are many online tracking pixel services providing Google Analytics integration, but you'll need one providing referral information in order to implement the scenario you described.